# Gradle getting error - HMS Core-Analytics Kit

Tags: analytics, huawei-mobile-services

Getting below error in gradle file after adding HMS analytics dependency.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven/com/huawei/agconnect/agcp/1.5.2.305/agcp-1.5.2.305.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Answer (score 0):

Please check your build.gradle/settings.gradle file and move

`maven { url'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/ '}` to the top in repositories block as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure below line is added in project level build.gradle file under **repositories** block

**{ url'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}**

Also make sure that this line should be added at the beginning of the **repositories** block as shown below

[sample build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lMaA.png)